# EXIT Trap with POSIX

Tags: shell, signals, posix, trap

I have a script I wrote in Bash that I'm trying to modify to be POSIX-compliant. I have managed to get everything working except I cannot get the EXIT trap to trigger when the process is terminated with killall, CTRL+C or closing the terminal - as it did with Bash. Here is my exit trap:

```
#!/bin/sh

TMP=$(mktemp /tmp/countdown.XXXXX)
trap 'rm -rf $TMP' EXIT
```

Comment: Is there still something that does not work by Kusalananda's answer?

Answer (score 8):

In a strictly POSIX shell, the `EXIT` trap is evaluated before the shell exits due to executing `exit` or due to executing the last command in a script. It is not executed if the shell exits due to a signal.

Would you want to catch <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, you would have to trap `INT` (the "interrupt" signal).  If closing the terminal sends the script a `HUP` ("hang-up") signal, you would have to trap that too.

```
trap 'rm -rf "$TMP"; trap - EXIT; exit' EXIT INT HUP
```

You may also want to trap `TERM`, the generic "terminate" signal sent by default by `kill`.

The trap above explicitly resets the `EXIT` trap so that it's not called *again* when the script exits due to receiving one of the listed signals.

Comment: about `exit` in a `SIGINT` trap: https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=wait+and+cooperative+exit

Comment: I guess you should trap even more signals, that have terminate as [default action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#Default_action), but signal POLL did not work with `dash`.

Comment: @jarno The built-in `kill` utility can be used to test what signals the shell understands: `dash -c 'kill -l'`.  I have personally never heard of a `POLL` signal.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Kusalananda, `EXIT` does not trap signals in POSIX. The simplest solution is to add something like this to your code:

```
trap exit INT HUP TERM
```

This will catch the signals you want and call your original trap when it reaches the exit statement.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the temporary file immediately after creating it, and read & write to it via a file descriptor.

Pass it as `/dev/fd/[fd]` or `/proc/self/fd/[fd]` to commands which expect a path.

Example:

```
t=$(mktemp); exec 5<>"$t"; rm "$t"

echo some text >&5
exec 5<>/dev/fd/5   # rewind / seek back at the start of the file
cat <&5

cmd1 /dev/fd/5  # cmd1 only takes paths
cmd2 5>&-       # don't leak fd 5 to cmd2
```

You can also open the tempfile as multiple *separate* fds, as in `exec 5<"$t" 6>"$t"`.

The rewind trick is linux-only; I cannot think of any portable way of doing it; ideas are welcome ;-\